# HttpPost method of PartialView in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, http-post, partial-views

I have a view that contain two partial views. One of them for creating, and the other is list of created(companies). My problem is that, when I try create `HttpPost` method does not work and calls only Index method again. Please help me to fix this problem.
This is my Index view

```
@model InvoiceModel.HelperClasses.CompanyViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Companies";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div id="companies">
    <div id="create">@Html.Partial("CreateCompany", Model.Create)</div>
    <div id="list">@Html.Partial("CompanyTable", Model.Companies)</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mind posting the rest of your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use @Html.BeginForm() to define your Model that you are creating so when you post it is all mapped up properly.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("(Action)", "(Controller)", FormMethod.Post, null))
{
    (Your model here)

    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}

<div id="list">@Html.Partial("CompanyTable", Model.Companies)</div>
```

Comment: Thank you,@kadumel. It worked well. I forgot this approach :D.